# Absolute Vertical Centering Technique with Image - Why is Firefox scaling image differently?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position, vertical-alignment

Technique in practice (works fine):

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css
(first example in article)

Results differ:

Chrome/Safari 'scale' a 100% width / height auto image using this technique from the vertical center within a 'mask' div with a fixed height of 300px and width of 100%. So when you increase the width of the container element, the image gets cropped equally on the top and bottom as it scales down, but the left and right edges 'stick' to the container (no horizontal cropping).

```
.container
{
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: 310px;
min-width: 462px;
}

img
{
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-height: 310px;
margin: auto;
}
```

**Here's the Fiddle** (sorry for the inline code) for you to check out:

**http://jsfiddle.net/KgJbR/**

With Firefox however, the image will 'scale' from an anchor point of the top-left corner, instead of an anchor point of dead-center, causing the image to be cropped only along the bottom. Is this just a low-level difference as to how the two engines work with this method?

Firefox is on the left, while Safari is on the right in this image. Red borders indicate where the image is being cropped.

[image: Firefox left, Safari right]

Comment: Wanna throw your markup into a fiddle for us to play with? There might be something you haven't provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers do handle Absolute Centering a bit differently! While in this case I'd recommend using a `background-image` instead for better positioning options, you can trick Firefox into centering the image appropriately using `top: -100%` and `bottom: -100%`. This forces Firefox to start its calculations for centering outside the container's bounds instead of starting the element at the top and only overflowing out the bottom.

Here's your Fiddle that's been tweaked to fix the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/KgJbR/3/

Comment: Awesome - thank you for the tip! It should be posted on the Smashing article in the comments, too. Re: bg image - the CMS I'm working with strips out `background-image` styles, unfortunately!

Comment: No problem! Sorry to hear about your CMS. What an odd style to strip!

Comment: Jive 5.0 w/formatting restrictions on. Makes it very difficult to style!